# Using a query/proc to run multiple queries

Tags: automation, call

I am fairly new to SQL so please bear with me.  I have 18 queries that I would like to run as 1 query.  They are very long and if I copy and paste them onto 1 query, it is too big to save.

Is there a way to call up these 18 queries and run them at once?  I know I could physically open them all and run them individually but I was hoping for a more automated process.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't need the results of the query.

On Microsoft sql Look up the sql Agent, there you can define one "job" with 18 steps running your queries.

Alternatively and On all other sql systems you can look at a commandline script to execute the query and then use a cronjob to run them automatically.